# multiple .replace gives NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, parsing

**Edit:**
The whole method is:

```
        public static String[] singlemultiplet(String filename, int numofzeros) throws IOException {//isolate notes between brackets
    Scanner inputmeasure = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer sbfFileContents = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            int lineCount = 0;
    int j = 0;
        int[] cmn = new int[countbrackets(filename)];
        String[] numbers = new String[40];
        String[][] matrix = new String[20][120];
        String[][] matrix2 = new String[20][120];
        String[][] matrix3 = new String[20][120];
            line = inputmeasure.useDelimiter("\n").next();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("U");
            matrix[0][0] = s.useDelimiter("\r").next();
            String ubar = "U|";
            matrix2[0][0] = matrix[0][0].replace("\\),","U").replaceAll("\\)","U").replace(ubar,"U");
            matrix3[0][0] = matrix2[0][0].replace("|","U");
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(matrix3[0][0]).useDelimiter("U");
            String brack = "(";
            String[] multiplet = new String[countmultipletsandmeasures(filename) + numofzeros];
            String[] multiplet2 = new String[countmultipletsandmeasures(filename) + numofzeros];
            Arrays.fill(multiplet, "");
            int cmampluszeros = countmultipletsandmeasures(filename) + numofzeros;
             for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)
             {
              matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();
              multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

             }
             lineCount++;
                    sbfFileContents.append(line);

            String strContent = sbfFileContents.toString();
    try {
        return multiplet;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that the method returns the array `multiplet` that contains chunks of the lines of `Matrix3[0]` to read in. The method must chunk the line as stated below, so when encountering ")," or "|".

When I try to read in the first line of `Matrix3[0]`:

```
(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|
```

the program gives chunks

```
multiplet[i]
```

as

```
multiplet: (A#,A#,A#
multiplet: ,(B#,B#,C#
multiplet: ,(B#,B#,C#
multiplet: ,(Bb,Bb,Cb
multiplet: (Ab,Ab,Ab
multiplet: ,(Bb,Bb,Cb
multiplet: ,(Bb,Bb,Cb
multiplet: ,(Bb,Bb,Cb
```

which is correct. But when I try to read in:
`(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|A#,B#,C#,D#, E#,F#,G#,  |  ,A,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  |` I get a `NoSuchElementException`. The correct output would be:

```
multiplet: (A#,A#,A#
multiplet: ,(B#,B#,C#
multiplet: ,(B#,B#,C#
multiplet: ,(Bb,Bb,Cb
multiplet: A#,B#,C#,D#, E#,F#,G#,  
multiplet:   ,A,  , ,   ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , ,   ,  ,  ,
```

Does anybody know why and what I should do to get the correct output?

**Edit:**

Debugging will give me the following stacktrace:

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,770 bci=322
>   2,770     multiplet[i] = matrix3[0][0];

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,767 bci=333
>   2,767                     for (int i = 0; i < cmampluszeros; i++)

main[1] step

> Step completed: 
>   Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", IOguitar.singlemultiplet(), line=2,769 bci=306
>   2,769    matrix3[0][0] = s2.useDelimiter("U").next();

main[1] step

> Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.main(), line=2,662 bci=35,573
>   2,662                                   e.printStackTrace();

main[1] step

> java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
>       at IOguitar.singlemultiplet(IOguitar.java:2769)
>       at IOguitar.countmultipletn(IOguitar.java:3121)
>       at IOguitar.main(IOguitar.java:187)

Step completed: "thread=main", IOguitar.main(), line=2,668 bci=35,578
2,668                               }

main[1]

But what do I have to do now?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Java: Write once, debug everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program step by step to better understand what happens?

Comment: I have posted the stacktrace under Edit.

Comment: Also, I think there's probably an easier way to achieve what you want. If you can explain what you actually want to achieve, that's probably a good way to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are an easier way to deal with this kind of parsing (it's made for it!). `String` has a convenient method, `split(String regex)`, that splits the string as you want it and places it in an array of Strings, just like you want it. The following line will do the trick:

```
String[] multiplet = "(A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|(Ab,Ab,Ab),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|".split("(\\)|\\|)+");
```

Explanation of regex:

```
\\)
```

`\\` escapes the `)` so it is a literal ")"

```
|
```

this means or in regex language.

```
\\|
```

literal "|"

```
("|" or ")")+
```

`+` means anything inside brackets should be at least once and is greedy (so if two or more of ) or | are adjacent it will split on all of them and not leave an empty String between them.

Comment: When I use .split("[\\)\\|]+|[\\|+]"); on the string (A#,A#,A#),(B#,B#,C#),(B#,B#,C#),(Bb,Bb,Cb)|A#,B#,C#,D#, E#,F#,G#, | ,A, , , , , , , , , , , , , , | I still get a NoSuchElementException. What to do now?

Comment: @user1189952 The .split("(\\)|\\|)+") works fine here.. Looks like you changed the regex?

Comment: I have the code:             String[] numbers = new String[40]; and                 while( (line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
                 numbers = line.split("[\\)\\|]+"); } so it is reading in that line. But with .split("(\)|\\|)+") I still get the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: The split() does the entire job for you - you don't need to call the scanner.next() after the regex.. I think it's still unclear how you want your end result. Regex can do a lot more things than just split that, it can really do all the parsing for you.